# Juntar Objetos que tenha alguma semelhança

Tags: javascript

Tem alguma maneira de juntar objetos que tenha alguma semelhança ? Por exemplo:

```js
var exemplo = [
  {'Title': 'exemple1', 'id': 15},
  {'Title': 'exemple1', 'id': 15},
  {'Title': 'exemple2', 'id': 20}
]
```

E ficar dessa maneira:

```js
var exemplo = [
  {'Title': 'exemple1', 'id': 15},
  {'Title': 'exemple2', 'id': 20},
]
```

Ou pegar com um loop apenas um dos objetos que são semelhantes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) do `array` para percorrer cada item e verificar se ele já está em um outro `array` de resultados (que será populado dentro do [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)).

```js
const exemplo = [
  {'Title': 'exemple1', 'id': 15},
  {'Title': 'exemple1', 'id': 15},
  {'Title': 'exemple2', 'id': 20},
];

const resultado = exemplo.reduce((acumulador, item) => {
  const filtrados = acumulador.filter((a) => a.Title == item.Title && a.id == item.id).length;
  filtrados > 0 || acumulador.push(item);
  return acumulador;
}, []);

console.log(resultado);
```

> [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
>
> O método `reduce()` executa uma função `reducer` (provida por você) para cada membro do array, resultando num único valor de retorno.
>
> **Exemplo:**
>
> ```js
> const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
> const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;
>
> // 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
> console.log(array1.reduce(reducer));
> // expected output: 10
>
> // 5 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
> console.log(array1.reduce(reducer, 5));
> // expected output: 15
> ```

---

> [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro)
>
> O método `filter()` cria um novo `array` com todos os elementos que passaram no teste implementado pela função fornecida.
>
> ```js
> function isBigEnough(value) {
>   return value >= 10;
> }
>
> var filtered = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44].filter(isBigEnough);
> // filtered é [12, 130, 44]
> console.log(filtered);
> ```

Comment: tem alguma maneira de pegar o mais recente(o mais embaixo) usando o mesmo script ? por exemplo em vez de pegar o **exemplo[0]** pegar o **exemplo[1**' ?

Comment: @JoãoVictor qual a diferença se são iguais??

Comment: com o script que você fez ele pega o primeiro dos que são semelhantes, eu queria de alguma maneira pegar o ultimo semelhante

Comment: @JoãoVictor eu entendi, só não entendi a finalidade

Comment: É meio difícil de explicar mais é o seguinte. Eu criei um script de history que ao fazer algumas ações em meu site ele seta um objeto em um array, para gravar a ação, e, em outra página eu pego esses objetos e coloco em uma lista. Na hora de colocar na lista eu queria apenas os mais recentes objetos semelhantes adicionados no array, pra não ficar uma lista enorme

Comment: @JoãoVictor me parece que o que realmente você quer fazer não é o que você perguntou. Você pode criar uma outra pergunta com um exemplo mais completo e mais próximo do que você quer, porque pra fazer essa alteração a resposta ficaria completamente diferente e não ia fazer sentido com essa pergunta